# How do i filter dropdownlist in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, filtering, dropdownlistfor

I have an Employee Class , which stores Employee Details , Name , Employee Skill etc. I have a Booking Class which allows the customer to choose an Employee for a particular booking. I have a drop down list to allow the customer to choose an employee for a booking. I want to filter the drop down list so that the customer can only pick employees according to the service required.

For example, if a customer requires a haircut , the drop down list must filter and only show the employees whose skill is a haircut.
I tried some code , but it didnt work. The drop down list is just blank

```
   //Employee Class
   [Key]
   public string EmployeeID { get; set;}

    public string EmployeeName { get; set;}

    public string Skill { get; set;}

    public string EmpStatus { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Booking { get; set;}

    //Booking Class
    public string BookingID { get; set;}
    [Remote("CheckCustomer", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Customer already exists in database.")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set;}

    public string CustomerName { get; set;}

    public string ServiceRequired { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public double Cost { get; set;}

    [PastDate]
    public DateTime BookingDate { get; set;}


    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set;}

    public string Status { get; set;}
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set;}



    //Create Action Method in Bookings Controller
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookingID,CustomerID,CustomerName,ServiceRequired,EmployeeID,Cost,BookingDate,Status")] Booking booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            booking.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

            db.Bookings.Add(booking);



            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        List<Employee> skillEmp = db.Employees.ToList().FindAll(x => x.Skill.Equals(booking.ServiceRequired));

        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(skillEmp, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName", booking.EmployeeID);
            return View(booking);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.Skill.Equals(booking.ServiceRequired)` checks, if both objects are the same instance - If I am not completely wrong than this has to be false, no matter which value `ServiceRequired` has.
you should use something like

```
x => x.Skill.IndexOf(booking.ServiceRequired) > -1
```

to match the string

Comment: Thanks for the help , i have tried that. Is there no way to make it automatically filter , and not when i click on the create button then it filters